# Why is the actor-critic algorithm limited to using on-policy data?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, actor-critic-methods, on-policy-methods, off-policy-methods

Why is the actor-critic algorithm limited to using on-policy data? Or can we use the actor-critic algorithm with off-policy data?

Answer (score 1):

It's because, in the actor-critic algorithm, the objective function is an expectation under the $\tau$ of the policy. If we want to use off-policy data, we have to resort to *importance sampling* relative to the other policy.

Comment: What does the tau value mean?